# unable to select drop down value

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

I am trying to select value from a drop down, but getting an error Element should have been "select" but was "mat-select". I am testing angularjs application and i am able to select drop down successfully..but i ger error when i try to select value inside the dropdown list.

Following is the method which i have used to select the element from the drop-down list:

```
public void clickandselectstoregroup(){
        WebElement storegroupIDdropdown = WebDriverUtils.getWebDriver().findElement(By.id(matselectStoreGroup));
        Select se = new Select(storegroupIDdropdown);
        se.selectByIndex(1);

    }
```

Error log:

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "mat-select"
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:14.666Z'
System info: host: '', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.<init>(Select.java:47)
    at com.morrisons.automation.pageobjects.sma.SchedulePageObject.clickandselectstoregroup(SchedulePageObject.java:225)
    at com.morrisons.automation.stepdefs.sma.NewScheduleStepDef.i_select_storegroup_dropdown_and_select_dropdown_value(NewScheduleStepDef.java:98)
    at ?.And I select storegroup dropdown and select dropdown value(C:/AutomationNeon1/atom/src/main/features/smascheduler/new-schedule.feature:22)
```

Comment: Is your question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like AngularJS doesn't have `select` element. It has something another, and WebDriver can't use your web element, like Select.

I haven't tested AngularJS.

However, I can suggest a solution, in this case, to use just native clicks there. You need to click on replacing select functionality:

- first for opening drop down list
- second, for selecting correct list element.

Code snippet should be something like:

```
DriverUtils.getWaiter().until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("vchannel_combobox"))).click();
DriverUtils.getWaiter().until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(
  String.format("//Rectangle[@id='vchannel_drop_down']/ListView/Item/Item[%d]", RandomUtils.nextInt(1, 4))))
).click();
```

At example below you can see exactly two appropriate actions. In that case, doesn't matter which element will be selected.
For selecting the correct element from list `Xpath` locator was used.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
Element should have been "select" but was "mat-select"
```

It is pretty clear the `WebElement` **`storegroupIDdropdown`** which have been identified as :

```
WebDriverUtils.getWebDriver().findElement(By.id(matselectStoreGroup));
```

This `WebElement` isn't defined within any **`<select>.....</select>`** tag. Rather it is defined within an **`<mat-select>.....</mat-select>`** tag.

Hence, moving ahead when you try to invoke **`selectByIndex(n)`** method (which can be invoked by **`Select`** type objects only) the current object is unable to invoke the method. Hence you see the error.

### Solution :

If you have a closer look at the **`HTML DOM`** you would either find a **`<select>.....</select>`** tag or a **`<ul>..<li>...</li>..</ul>`** tag which controls the **`DropDown`**. You need to identify those and work with them.